What is causing this ZPL code to print incorrectly?
This ZPL code previews on Labelary in the right way and actually worked a month ago. Now when I print it everything is blank except the image and the text is turned horizontally.
^XA

^FO45,15
...IMAGE ZPL...

^FO36,16^GB840,95,4^FS  
^FO156,16^GB4,95,4^FS  
^FO500,16^GB4,95,4^FS  
^FO730,16^GB4,95,4^FS

^CFJ,14,14
^FB334,1,0,C,0  
^FO166,23^FDManufacturer Stipulates Conformance To:^FS
^CF0,30,30  
^FB334,1,0,C,0  
^FO166,56^FDNFRC 100/200/500^FS

^CFJ,14,14  
^FB224,1,0,C,0  
^FO506,23^FDComfort View Products^FS
^CFJ,12,12
^FB224,5,0,C,0
^FO506,37^FDNewnan, GA^FS
^FB224,5,0,C,0
^FO506,57^FDProduct:^
^FS
^FB224,5,0,C,0
^FO506,70^FD{%PRDCT%}^FS
^FB224,5,0,C,0
^FO506,95^FDIG NO. NAMI-102111^FS

^CF0,30,30  
^FB224,1,0,C,0  
^FO694,40^FDNFRC^FS  
^CF0,20,20  
^FB224,1,0,C,0  
^FO694,70^FD{%CVPM%}^FS

^CF0,12,12^FWB  
^FO22,6^FD{%12345%}^FS

^XZ

This is what it is supposed to look like, instead the text is turned 90 degrees and has is falling off of the bottom within each section. The only thing that is correct is the borders, image, and outside horizontal number. I can't figure out if it is a zpl problem or a printer problem?

You can paste your ZPL on this site (https://labelary.com/viewer.html), and check for the errors.... (messages like: ^FD: Field block is centered but does not end with a line separator (\&), which is likely to cause text layout issues )

That's what I've been using. I used the line separators and it still didn't change anything except shift the preview a little to the right. The label printed out still incorrectly.

When using ^FO166,23^FDManufacturer Stipulates Conformance To:\&^FS I do see 1 error go.  (I am ignoring the missing image...)

Yes that's why I'm saying that the previewer looks correct with and without the separators but after being printed the text is almost all flipped and stacked at the bottom/past the bottom.

Have you tried resetting your printer to factory defaults?

Yes that did not work either :(. Thank you guys for the help so far though

There are orientation and other commands that the printer can keep from label to label. It is a best practice to set those at the beginning of your zpl. I think orientation is ^PO.
